# How can I feature geojson information in a popup in leaflet

Tags: javascript, leaflet, geojson

https://github.com/mysidewalk/interview/blob/master/assets/kc-neighborhoods.json

Github displays this geojson well, and has popups on click featuring properties of the geojson.

Here is my example. http://www.datafix.io/data-source/2/geojson-example/
I am only able to visualize the polygons, and not the popups. How does github do it? I am quite new to this.

My code:

```
function loadMap(){
    map = L.map('visualizations');
    osmUrl='http://{s}.tile.openstreetmap.org/{z}/{x}/{y}.png';
    osmAttrib='Map data © <a href="http://openstreetmap.org">OpenStreetMap</a> contributors';
    osm = new L.TileLayer(osmUrl, {minZoom: 8, maxZoom: 12, attribution: osmAttrib});       
    map.addLayer(osm);

    $.getJSON(GData.csvURL, function(data){
        var feature = L.geoJson(data).addTo(map);
        map.fitBounds(feature.getBounds());
    });
}

loadMap()
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to follow the step by step guide [here](https://leafletjs.com/examples/geojson/) and construct a `table` instead of a `p` inside the `popup`. Then you can check the console by inspecting each element on the example you provide and get the exact css.

The onEachFeature provides all the information you will need to get the `json` metadata.

```
const onEachFeature = (feature, layer) => {
  // eslint-disable-line no-use-before-define
  const popupContent = `
  <table>
  <tr>
    <th>id:</th>
    <td>${feature.properties.id}</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <th>shid:</th>
    <td>${feature.properties.shid}</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <th>area:</th>
    <td>${feature.properties.area}</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <th>pop-commute-drive_alone:</th>
    <td>${feature.properties["pop-commute-drive_alone"]}</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <th>pop-commute-drive_carpool:</th>
    <td>${feature.properties["pop-commute-drive_carpool"]}</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <th>pop-commute-public_transit:</th>
    <td>${feature.properties["pop-commute-public_transit"]}</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <th>pop-commute-drive_alone:</th>
    <td>${feature.properties["pop-commute-walk"]}</td>
  </tr>
</table>`;

  if (feature.properties && feature.properties.popupContent) {
    popupContent += feature.properties.popupContent;
  }

  layer.bindPopup(popupContent);
}

const feature = L.geoJSON(json, {
  onEachFeature: onEachFeature
}).addTo(map);
map.fitBounds(feature.getBounds());
```

You can refactor `onEachFeature` function to be more elegant. I just want you to get the idea here.

In the [demo](https://codesandbox.io/s/8k913m2vxj) you can see the css I applied to achieve a similar look with the example

Comment: Ideally, I'm looking for a way to do this with any geojson (like github/geojson.io) -- not specialized to one geojson object

Comment: Looking at your code a bit more, maybe you've given enough info for me to do this. Please stick around though, I still need help

Comment: You are right. I think I gave you too much info to be able to continue. You just add the getJson method and you are ready to go. Plus you question has to do only with populating the popup with json info. Please accept and/or upvote the answer if it helped you

Comment: Wait what do you mean (about the $.getJson)? I was thinking of producing the table programmatically. Can you edit your answer? Just upvoted you, will accept your answer once I have a clear way to go about doing this.

Comment: I mean that in the provided example I am importing a json  residing locally while in yours you make a request to get the json